# Regex for spliting on all unescaped semi-colons

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using php's [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split up a string based on semi-colons, but I need it to only split on non-escaped semi-colons.

```
<?
$str = "abc;def\\;abc;def";
$arr = preg_split("/;/", $str);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => def\
    [2] => abc
    [3] => def
)
```

When I want it to produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => def\;abc
    [2] => def
)
```

I've tried `"/(^\\)?;/"` or `"/[^\\]?;/"` but they both produce errors. Any ideas?

Comment: @Corey, why is the semi-colon escaped if you don't want it in your final output?

Comment: @Doug Typo, added semi colon in final output

Comment: Can the escapes be escaped? In other words, can a string literal look like this: `"abc;def\\\\;abc;def"` (split into: `[abc, def\\, abc, def`] )?

Comment: The colon in your string doesn't really look escaped to me: it looks like a regular colon preceded by an escaped backslash. I think you need `\\\;` if you want `\;` in output, `\;` if you just want an escaped `;`

Comment: @kemp: `\\;` in a string literal becomes `\;` in the string, which is exactly what Corey wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works.

```
<?
  $str = "abc;def\;abc;def";
  $arr = preg_split('/(?<!\\\);/', $str);
  print_r($arr);
?>
```

It outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => def\;abc
    [2] => def
)
```

You need to make use of a negative lookbehind ([read about lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)). Think of "match all ';' unless preceed by a '\'".

Comment: That will work unless you have an element that ends with a backslash - there is no way to escape that backslash, since to the regex it looks like it's escaping the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really proficient with PHP regexes, but try this one:

```
/(?<!\\);/
```

Comment: It needs to be a triple '\'. Using only 2 produced errors here. Not sure why this is so.

Comment: Your answer works with triple '\', but Nils went the extra step in explaining why. Get a +1 for effort though!

Answer (score 0):

Since Bart asks: Of course you can also use regex to split on unescaped ; and take escaped escape characters into account. It just gets a bit messy:

```
<?
  $str = "abc;def\;abc\\\\;def";
  preg_match_all('/((?:[^\\\\;]|\\\.)*)(?:;|$)/', $str, $arr);
  print_r($arr);
?>

Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [0] => abc;
          [1] => def\;abc\\;
          [2] => def
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [0] => abc
          [1] => def\;abc\\
          [2] => def
      )
)
```

What this does is to take a regular expression for “(any character except \ and ;) or (\ followed by any character)” and allow any number of those, followed by a ; or the end of the string.

I'm not sure how php handles $ and end-of-line characters within a string, you may need to set some regex options to get exactly what you want for those.